# Batch insert in PostgreSQL extremely slow (F#)

Tags: postgresql, f#

The code is in F#, but it's generic enough that it'll make sense to anyone not familiar with the language.

I have the following schema:

```
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS trades_buffer (
            instrument varchar NOT NULL,
            ts timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
            price decimal NOT NULL,
            volume decimal NOT NULL
        );

        CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_instrument ON trades_buffer(instrument);
        CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_ts ON trades_buffer(ts);
```

My batches are made of 500 to 3000 records at once. To get an idea of the performance, I'm developing on a 2019 MBP (i7 CPU), running PostgreSQL in a Docker container.
Currently it will take between 20 and 80 seconds to insert a batch; while the size / time is not really linear, it scales somewhat.

I'm using this lib https://github.com/Zaid-Ajaj/Npgsql.FSharp as a wrapper around Npgsql.

This is my insertion code:

```
let insertTradesAsync (trades: TradeData list) : Async<Result<int, Exception>> =
    async {
        try
            let data =
                trades
                |> List.map (fun t ->
                        [
                            "@instrument", Sql.text      t.Instrument.Ticker
                            "@ts",         Sql.timestamp t.Timestamp.DateTime
                            "@price",      Sql.decimal   t.Price
                            "@volume",     Sql.decimal   (t.Quantity * t.Price)
                        ]
                    )

            let! result =
                connectionString
                |> Sql.connect
                |> Sql.executeTransactionAsync [ "INSERT INTO buffer_trades (instrument, ts, price, volume) VALUES (@instrument, @ts, @price, @volume)", data]
                |> Async.AwaitTask
            return Ok (List.sum result)

        with ex ->
            return Error ex
    }
```

I checked that the connection step is extremely fast (<1ms).
pgAdmin seems to show that the PostGreSQL is mostly idle.
I ran profiling on the code and none of this code seem to take any time.
It's as if the time spent was in the driver, between my code and the database itself.

Since I'm a newbie with PostGreSQL, I could also be doing something horribly wrong :D

---

Edit:

I have tried a few things:

- use the TimeScale plugin, made for time series
- move the data from a docker volume to a local folder
- run the code on a ridiculously large PostgreSQL AWS instance

and the results are the same.

What I know now:

- no high CPU usage
- no high ram usage
- no hotspot in the profile on my code
- pgAdmin shows the db is mostly idle
- having an index, or not, has no impact
- local or remote database gives the same results

So the issue is either:

- how I interact with the DB
- in the driver I'm using

Update 2:

The non async version of the connector performs significantly better.

Comment: Normally `\copy` is the best option to import large files into postgres, but if you must use `f#`, consider creating the indexes only **after** the import is done. Otherwise postgres will sort the table after every single insert. cheers

Comment: It’s not an import, it’s live data coming in. I used to write that volume in mongo without issues but for some reason this is very very slow here. Or is Postgres not suitable for writing that volume live? (It’s financial trades coming in through a socket) it’s the first time I try to implement this with a sql solution.

Comment: I see. Well, there will always be a certain overhead with the indexes while inserting, deleting or updating data. Perhaps a "columnar" table could speed up things a little. Take a look at the citus extension for postgres. Cheers and happy coding

Comment: I tried to not have any index on the table but it didn’t seem to change much. Thanks for the suggestion, I’ll also be looking at Timescale. I wanted to make sure I’m not doing something horribly wrong and obvious beforehand.

Comment: [Npgsql.FSharp is using a task builder](https://github.com/Zaid-Ajaj/Npgsql.FSharp/blob/50d3409fec844526e3c44901d64c8361b09e42a3/src/Npgsql.FSharp.fs#L286) from [Ply](https://github.com/crowded/ply). If possible, it might be worth trying to use that library yourself and then just keep the task instead of converting it to async.